# Convergence of Dirichlet series related to Fibonacci numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Let $z(n)$ be the rank of apparition in the Fibonacci sequence, i.e., $z(n)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $n$ divides $F_k$. A well-known result is that $z(n)\leq 2n$, for all $n\geq 1$ with equality iff $n=6\cdot 5^k$, for $k\geq 0$.

I would like to prove that the series
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\displaystyle\frac{z(n)}{n^2}
$$
diverges.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: $z(p)$ is more or less the order of $(1+\sqrt{5})/2\in \Bbb{F}_p(\sqrt{5})^\times$. Then $z(p^k) | p\, z(p^{k-1})$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1\implies z(ab)=lcm(z(a),z(b))$ thus $\sum_n z(n)n^{-2}$ converges iff $\sum_p z(p)p^{-2}$ converges. If $p=aq+1$ with $q$ prime and $(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^a\le p-1$ then $q \ | \ z(p)$. But the density of those primes such that $p-1$'s largest prime factor is $\ge \frac{p}{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\log p}$ is too low to give the divergence of $\sum_p z(p)p^{-2}$ (it gives the divergence of $\sum_p z(p)p^{\epsilon-2}$).

Comment: @reuns thanks, but could you please explain me better. For example, I didn't understand two points: (1) $\sum_nz(n)n^{-2}$ converges iff  $\sum_pz(p)p^{-2}$ converges. (2) What is the density of primes with that lower for the largest prime factor of $p-1$? and why this implies in the divergence of  $\sum_pz(p)p^{-2+\epsilon}$?

Comment: Thanks @reuns But about my question (2)? Could you please explain me better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $Z(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n} p^{k-1}z(p)$ (which is multiplicative) then (for $5\nmid n$) $z(n)\le Z(n)$ and $\sum_n z(n)n^{-s}$ converges implies that $\sum_p Z(p)p^{-s}$ converges, conversely if $s > 1$ and the latter converges then so does $\sum_p \log (1+\sum_{k\ge 1} Z(p^k) p^{-sk})=\log( \sum_n Z(n)n^{-s})$. For the density of the above primes it is a guess, it is very possible you need some strong conjecture. To predict the densities you can use that given $q,a$ the "probability" that $qa+1$ is prime is about $1/\log(qa)$